# innodb corrupt database - recover events and functions

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

There is plenty of articles how to restore the data but can't find anything about the scheduled events and functions recovery.

The db crashed due to running out of disk space (plesk). I managed to get the data back from the daily sql dump, but the 30+ events I got no backup. I have all the .ibd and .frm files, also there are event.MYD and event.MYI files. Copying those to the working db does nothing naturally.

Is there a way to recover the MySQL events?

Comment: This question is likely to attract more relevant answers on a different site of StackExchange network, https://dba.stackexchange.com/. I've just voted to move this question there.

Comment: Are you asking about `EVENT` definitions?  Or the execution of those events?  What command was used to do the backup?  And what version of MySQL?

Comment: Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev

The EVENT definitions. They consist of multiple queries each, ALTER and UPDATE etc. I need those back.

The backup was done is SSH with cp command, they are raw files. Replacing the backup folder results in error, there is something corrupt inside, so can't use it in full.